# how to play a video file in background?

Tags: android, android-video-player

I need to play the downloaded .mts video file in background to take the thumbnail and duration of the video file . I would like to know,is it possible to play a video file in background?

I tried it by using an Asyntask but it fails.

```
Utils.writeImageToFile(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                                            f.getAbsolutePath(),
                                            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND),
                                            String.format("%s%s", thumbPath, name.substring(0, name.length() - 4)),
                                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70);
                                    msg.obj = new VideoHelerNew(f, duration);
                                    System.out.println("" + duration.toString() + "hhhh" + duration);
                                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

I already tried this method. But .mts video will not suppot native videoplayer. May be due to this I couldnt generate the thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

It does not make any sense to play video in background. But if your purpose is just to get thumbnail of video file then you can use below code

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

For further information you may refer below link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Key point to remember is
Create a video thumbnail for a video. May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported.

For further help I am sharing a link that will help you what formats are supported in android

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: Hi, I tried this method already.  I have edited my question.Please have a look